# to log and store Postgres errors?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, compiler-errors, error-logging, error-log

I have a requirement to capture all the database errors arrived while calling a procedure/function, inserting a record in a table or deleting.
Its something like whenever any errors occurs in Postgres database, that needs to be captured. 
Can any one suggest me some like or any small example stating that.

Till now I was using:
Raise notice or Raise exception to raise it on console log.
But I want to capture these and store in a table(some error log table).

I have set below parameters in postgresql.conf:

```
log_destination = 'stderr','csvlog','syslog','eventlog'
logging_collector = on
log_filename = 'tst_log_err-%a.log'
client_min_messages = debug5
log_min_messages = debug5
log_min_error_statement = debug5
log_min_duration_statement = 300ms
log_checkpoints = on
log_line_prefix =  '%t [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,app=%a,client=%h '
log_lock_waits = on
log_statement = 'all'
```

and then created table "postgres_log" with all the specified details.

And then tried stopping and restarting local postgresql server but I got failed to restart

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

set `logging_collector` to `on`, `log_destination` to `stderr,csvlog`, `log_min_error_statement` to `NOTICE` (if you want higher then NOTICE to be saved in logs). Eg `log_min_error_statement` = `NOTICE` this will capture all you `rase NOTICE`, `raise WARNING` and so on;  `log_min_error_statement` = `WARNING` this will capture all you `rase WARNING`, `raise error` and so on.

then, follow
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG

you can setup cron to load it periodically...

Comment: I have set below parameters in postgresql.conf:
log_destination = 'stderr','csvlog','syslog','eventlog'
logging_collector = on
log_filename = 'tst_log_err-%a.log'
client_min_messages = debug5
log_min_messages = debug5
log_min_error_statement = debug5
log_min_duration_statement = 300ms
log_checkpoints = on
log_line_prefix =  '%t [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,app=%a,client=%h '
log_lock_waits = on
log_statement = 'all'

and then created table "postgres_log" with all the specified details.

And then tried stopping and restarting local postgresql server but I got failed to restart

Comment: I am getting below error, at the time of login after restarting.
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: And once I change postgresql.conf content as that of previous one, it start normally.

Comment: this error when connecting to server that fails to start. no use. please find startup error - look in `$PGDATA/pg_log/` directory

Comment: I am able to track the issue now.
Could you please help me if we can log application related exception and database related errors individually?
Currently we are migrating Oracle to Postgres, in Oracle for each application error we are handlig and storing these errors in a table and those table entries are made time to time.
So I am trying to replicate the scenario.
Kindly help me incase if you are aware of any idea regarding same

Comment: please post a NEW clear question and I (and many more better devs) will gladly try to help you with it

Comment: PF Question 46345985